# Did my pot really reach >400°C internally while heating water (soup broth)

Tags: temperature, electromagnetic-induction, metals

I have a 1800W induction cooktop.

In my experiment, did the following steps:

1. I placed a stainless pot on the cooktop, half filled with fridge cold chicken broth.
2. I heated the pot at 1000W until I could feel the bottom sides of the pot getting too hot to touch.
3. I set the induction power to the maximum of 1800W.
4. I waited until the broth was just starting to boil and the surface would read about 96°C.

To my surprise, I noticed I had what I think is heat inflicted discolouration on the inner bottom of my pot:

[image]

According to [this site](https://bssa.org.uk/bssa_articles/heat-tint-temper-colours-on-stainless-steel-surface-heated-in-air/), those colours would mean temperatures high of 400°C.

I assumed the broth would cool the bottom as long as it wasn't boiling too much and would keep it at a nice temperature around 100°C but the discolouration seems to point otherwise.

Am I misinterpreting this discolouration?

Comment: Every site I query reads they can easily heat an appropriate metal pan above 500-600 degrees.

Comment: You are not heating the bottom of the pan in air - it is in water (mostly). Different reactions.

Comment: *"Am I misinterpreting this discolouration?"* Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the discoloration wasn't there before your experiment? Because what you are looking at are layers of transparent chromium oxide on the pot bottom that are just thick enough to create colored interference fringes. To form them on chrome or stainless steel normally requires extended exposure to temperatures typical of the exhaust stacks on a Kawasaki Vulcan 1500 motorcycle engine at extended cruise conditions (hot enough to inflict 3rd degree burns on human skin pressed against the pipes). I know this from first-hand experience.

If the pot was full of boiling water while the oxide layer was formed, this would require that the heat flux through the pot bottom be sufficient to blanket the entire bottom of the pot with a continuous layer of steam so the bottom would *boil dry*; only then could the temperature of the pot bottom get high enough to grow that oxide.

On the other hand, dry-firing the pot (no water in it while adding heat) would build an oxide just like that in minutes.

The other possibility was that the soup was sufficiently acidic to either 1) etch away the existing uniform oxide on the pot bottom at the temperature of boiling water, yielding a temperature map on the pot bottom, or 2) to thicken the native (very thin) oxide layer enough to yield fringes.

Comment: Instead of something so severe as a continuous layer of steam, what about gas pockets from bubbles against the over a long period of time?

Comment: @DKNguyen, doubtful in my experience with oxidizing thin metal films in oxygen atmospheres.

Answer (score 0):

The discolouration is likely due to a thin layer of organic molecules and oxides. I see no reason why you need to assume a high temperature to get that?